# how to replace partial content of JS object array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JS object array as :

```
[
  { workoutName: 'Farmers Walk' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Lateral Lunge Hop (Left)' },
  { workoutName: 'Dumbbell Cross Chops (Right)' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Oblique Jumping Jacks' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Wide Press Parallel' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Single Leg Lunge Jump (Left)' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Jump Squat' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Squat to Toe Tap' }
]
```

I'm saving the objects that are (Left) & (Right) to a new array.

```
let substrL = 'Left'
let substrR = 'Right'
let remaining = [] 
  results.find((o) => {
     if (o.workoutName.includes (substrR) || o.workoutName.includes (substrL))
     //results.map(obj => ({ workoutName: obj.workoutName.replace('Left','Right')}))
          remaining.push(o)
  
  });
```

What I cannot do is, I'm trying to replace the partial string of the remaining[] array.

in this example , the results are is

```
[
  { workoutName: 'BW Lateral Lunge Hop (Left)' },
  { workoutName: 'Dumbbell Cross Chops (Right)' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Single Leg Lunge Jump (Left)' }
]
```

what I would like to do / the expected outcome is to have the opposite of the results arr.

```
[
   { workoutName: 'BW Lateral Lunge Hop (Left)' }, //workoutName: 'BW Lateral Lunge Hop (Right)'
   { workoutName: 'Dumbbell Cross Chops (Right)' },//workoutName: 'Dumbbell Cross Chops (Left)'
   { workoutName: 'BW Single Leg Lunge Jump (Left)' }//workoutName: 'BW Single Leg Lunge Jump (Right)'
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything and just needed the opposite of what is present. Without affecting the original object, you can use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator to store the object, then check what type of content is stored within the parentheses, and alter them:

```js
var results = [
  { workoutName: 'Farmers Walk' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Lateral Lunge Hop (Left)' },
  { workoutName: 'Dumbbell Cross Chops (Right)' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Oblique Jumping Jacks' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Wide Press Parallel' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Single Leg Lunge Jump (Left)' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Jump Squat' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Squat to Toe Tap' }
]

let substrL = 'Left'
let substrR = 'Right'
let remaining = []
results.find((o) => {
  if (o.workoutName.includes(substrR) || o.workoutName.includes(substrL)) {
    let data = { ...o }
    if (o.workoutName.includes(substrR))
      data.workoutName = o.workoutName.replace(substrR, substrL)
    else
      data.workoutName = o.workoutName.replace(substrL, substrR)
    remaining.push(data)
  }
});

console.log(remaining)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd think about this in terms of a map on the original array, producing an array of the original objects with new props.

```js
const array = [
  { workoutName: 'Farmers Walk' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Lateral Lunge Hop (Left)' },
  { workoutName: 'Dumbbell Cross Chops (Right)' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Oblique Jumping Jacks' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Wide Press Parallel' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Single Leg Lunge Jump (Left)' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Jump Squat' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Squat to Toe Tap' }
];

const directionWords = [ "Left", "Right" ];
const complements = { Left: "Right", Right: "Left" };
const augmentedArray = array.map(obj => {
  const directionWord = directionWords.find(word => obj.workoutName.includes(word));
  if (directionWord) {
    const complement = complements[directionWord];
    const complementName = obj.workoutName.replace(directionWord, complement);
    return { ...obj, directionWord, complement, complementName }
  }
  return obj;
})

console.log(augmentedArray)
```

Any result we might want can now be extracted.  For example, the OP's "remainder" objects, with updated names...

```js
const array = [
  { workoutName: 'Farmers Walk' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Lateral Lunge Hop (Left)' },
  { workoutName: 'Dumbbell Cross Chops (Right)' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Oblique Jumping Jacks' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Wide Press Parallel' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Single Leg Lunge Jump (Left)' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Jump Squat' },
  { workoutName: 'BW Squat to Toe Tap' }
];

const directionWords = [ "Left", "Right" ];
const complements = { Left: "Right", Right: "Left" };
const augmentedArray = array.map(obj => {
  const directionWord = directionWords.find(word => obj.workoutName.includes(word));
  if (directionWord) {
    const complement = complements[directionWord];
    const complementName = obj.workoutName.replace(directionWord, complement);
    return { ...obj, directionWord, complement, complementName }
  }
  return obj;
})

const updatedRemainders = augmentedArray
  .filter(obj => obj.complementName)
  .map(obj => ({ workoutName: obj.complementName }));
console.log(updatedRemainders)
```